# Exclude section of code from code formatting

Tags: php, netbeans, autoformatting

Is there a comment tag in which I can enclose a section (of php code) which the auto formatter will ignore?

Sometimes I use a unique indention style for a tricky section of php code. For example if I pass several arrays i initialize in-line. It is sometimes the only way to keep things readable. Unfortunately this is lost after applying the code formatter.

Comment: There is no universal solution that would work for every code formatter. The answer depends on which one you're using, however, 'not possible' is likely the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by which code formatter. I use the integrated php code formatter that ships with Netbeans 7 RC1 php distro. Could be I'm looking a feature that's not there (yet).

Comment: Please provide a sample of code formatted by auto-formatter and the same code formatted like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways you may comment code:

```
// comment out a single line
```

You can also use a shell style comment in the middle of code like,

```
<h1>This is an <?php # echo 'simple';?> example</h1>
```

The header above will say 'This is an  example'.

Then finally you can do multi line comments like,

```
/* line one
line two and
line three are commented */
```